# non-greedy / lazy matches with KATE regex

Tags: regex, kate

I'm trying to find everything between two words (not going to say which two words because I don't want people screaming "you can't parse x with regexes, use an x parser instead). I have no trouble finding the start word and the end word - except that the end word isn't the first one encountered.

What I'm using is something like: `startword((.*\n)*)endword`

This isn't as bad as leaving off the endword, which then matches to the end of the document. However it's not what I need.

I've read umpteen articles saying what I want is a non-greedy or lazy search that should be turned on by putting a ? after the **. When I try that in KATE, it matches nothing (`startword((.*\n)*?)endword`).

I'm also puzzled by another behaviour - I have some text where endword\n\s**endword occurs but when I use that to end the match, it also fails. However the match endword\n\s*endword by itself operates as expected.

Is there a way to do lazy regexes in KATE, or can anyone come up with another solution?

Thanks.

Comment: *It documents regular expressions in the form available within KatePart, which is **not compatible with the regular expressions of perl**, nor with those of for example grep.*

Comment: [The quantifiers](https://docs.kde.org/stable5/en/applications/katepart/quantifiers.html) listed has no lazy quantifiers among them, so they are not supported.

Comment: I see lookaheads are supported. Try `startword([^e]*(?:e(?!ndword)[^e]*)*)endword` ([demo](https://regex101.com/r/pmge9k/1))

Comment: Thanks Wiktor. Unfortunately I can't get that to work either. Lookaheads seem to have a lot of variation in implementation...

Answer (score 0):

For some reason (probably related to my inadequate understanding of regexes), something I tried earlier finally worked. Rather than having an indefinite number of lines between the start word and the end word, I was able to specify it as an indefinite number of lines in the form `(startword2.*endword2)*`

This removed the need to do a lazy evaluation.